# How to customize a Windows boot CD

Tags: windows, live-cd, system-restore

What is the easiest way to make a Windows boot CD that can be customized?

Specifically I would like to run [DriveSnapshot](http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/) from a boot CD so that I can restore images from a USB drive.  I tried [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) a while ago but was never able to get it to work due to no USB support on the PC.

I know there are a lot of *nix based CDs out there, but Drivesnapshot needs to run on Windows.  It works fine on a simple boot floppy but not many PCs have floppy drives anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) for this.  Find some good guides on setting it up here:
http://www.nu2.nu/bootcd/

You'll need a full XP *retail* license for this, and even then there's some question.

Comment: BartPE for the win!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to follow the tutorial on the DriveSnapshot site: [**How to create a bootable CD/DVD**](http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/bootcd.htm)?

Comment: No, now that you mention it.  That sounds easier than what I was trying to do before...wonder if it would have USB support?

Answer (score 1):

Windows PE itself can do this too, and it's no longer encumbered by licensing restrictions.  Despite being Vista-based, I've used it for deploying a few thousand XP images (and the PCs in question are still up and running over 2 years on).

Pros: you can load drivers while it's running, extremely good hardware support (USB out of the box), can run Win32 apps, very scriptable, supported by MS.

Cons: bit of a steep learning curve, needs 512 MB RAM.

Do a search for Windows AIK on www.microsoft.com and you'll be getting started.  Their "Malware Removal Kit" instructions probably provide the best "how to" documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I use UBCD4Win which is better than just the UBCD, this is based on the BartPE as well and it already has a lot of useful tools. What I like about it is that it also has a forum so you can see what other people have done and tried.

Check out [UBCD4Win.com](http://UBCD4Win.com) for more info.

Comment: +1 -I use DriveImageXML for my disk images from the UBCD4Win Disc. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at building a [BartPE disk](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/). (I think it goes under a different name now, and I think the [other link](http://www.nu2.nu/bootcd/) is to a similar project.)

You will need an existing XP disk and licence to create it, but I've used it to successfully rescue some files from a jacked up laptop that my usual Ubuntu Live CD couldn't get to.

Last I checked there are some good plugins for BartPE for a lot of common disk imaging/recovery apps.

You may want to look at using [PING](http://ping.windowsdream.com/) to create the images in the future as it will let you make your own "recovery CDs". I've used it in the past for some family work.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.ratsauce.co.uk/notablog/WinPECD.asp for my walkthrough of making a WinPE boot CD.

JR

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a customized Windows CD, look for nLite.  As for a bootable Windows CD, BartPE, mentioned above, is your best bet.